# Display Moment.js in different locale

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), I can't determine the way to show a date in a defined locale (eg. Fr). Any help is appreciated.

```
<script>
    var NowMoment = moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do");

    // display value of moment object in #displayMoment div
    var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('displayMoment');
    eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = NowMoment;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add moment+locales.js or the locale/fr.js that you need...

```js
moment.locale('fr');

var NowMoment = moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do");

    // display value of moment object in #displayMoment div
    var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('displayMoment');
    eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = NowMoment;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<div id="displayMoment"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do:

```
<script>
    var NowMoment = moment();
    NowMoment.tz('Europe/Paris').format("dddd, MMMM Do");

    // display value of moment object in #displayMoment div
    var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('displayMoment');
    eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = NowMoment;
</script>
```

I am not 100% sure it works as I am not able to test it. I got it from http://momentjs.com/timezone/